# Does the link to an arxiv article change if I update the article?

Tags: arxiv, preprint

As the title says, I am submitting a preprint to arxive. If I have a copy of the link to the article, does the link change when I upload an updated version of the same article?

Comment: If the link doesn't include a version number, it will always point to the most recent version of the article. It is also possible to produce links that point to specific earlier versions (but I've never done that).

Comment: Thanks. How would you get the link that points to the most recent version of the article?

Comment: @Morcus: It's the default. There's just no "vX", where x is the version number, at the end.

Answer (score 10):

You can produce both links that include a version number, and links without one that point to the most recent version. The link names are quite explanatory; for instance (from one of my articles):

- https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06459
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06459v1
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06459v2